# Remove path from environment variables

Tags: macos, bash

For mistake I have added a path that I don't want to use.
I have create a file named .base_profile, exported the path using the command source .base_profile, but I don't need this path, how to delete it?

Maybe the title wasn't so appropriate, but I haven't modified the PATH variable.
I have written this in the .base_profile file:

```
export MP=$MP/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

And then used the source command.The problem is with the MP variable, which is not one that I want, it's too long.I want to delete it, how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do an

```
echo $PATH
```

Then grab with the mouse that part, which looks useful, and append it to:

```
PATH=
```

So for example - not on an OSX-System:

```
PATH=/home/ramy/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

If you only sourced the path in one terminal, you can, alternatively, open a new terminal.

If you added the source-command to one configuration script, you have to remove it there, to get rid of it permananetly.

Comment: It ended up that I've found the unset command and used it.I solved the problem now.

Answer (score 7):

The way to restore your path to the default is `PATH=$(getconf PATH)`

Answer (score 2):

Fix your errors in the file, and fix the env var with

export PATH=[the correct one]